# Problem with applying image on a displacement map, displacement apply on top and bottom but not on sides

Tags: image, displacement

I tried to search over the net but it seems nobody as the same problem...

I try to apply a displacement map from an image and it seems that whatever option I choose from `Image Mapping`, `Texture Coordinates`, `Direction` .etc, it is always like if the image has been projected from top and bottom, streching texture on the sides...

[image: Top view and side view]

Does anyone have the solution ?

**EDIT:** image of my settings
[image]

Comment: You probably need to unwrap your mesh and use a UV Map

Comment: What coordinates are you using to map the image on to the sphere? Please edit your question and add an image of the texture mapping settings.

Comment: In the displace modifier is the *Direction* set to *Normal*?

Comment: I am using Normal direction and Local Object coordinates, but I tried all of them and nothing seems to work...
@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Can you explain further please ? I'm new to blender :p
Also, everything is ok when I use predefined textures...

Comment: [Blender Unwrap tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20unwrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Try generated coordinates with Sphere projection. You do not need to UV unwrap for this.

**Updated** (after review file):

The question is related to applying an image texture to the Displace modifier in Blender Render. In Blender Render you can do a few more things with 'normal' textures like Sphere projection that are not available with the Displace modifier image texture - as far as I know. The distortion has to do with the way the square textures are tiled around the sphere.

The issue is further exaggerated by the scale not having being applied.

[image]

Left is the original sphere, and right with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and having scale applied. The texture was set to extend, but has been set here to repeat to avoid distortion after the scale was applied.

Some options would be to consider UV unwrapping, as Duarte suggested. This would cause seams that might be hidden by a procedural texture over this like *Clouds*.

The Displace modifier has been somewhat eclipsed by [True Displacement](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html) which is available in Cycles Render - not Blender Render. It has the advantage that it can be used in combination with [Adaptive Subdivision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/objects/adaptive_subsurf.html#render-cycles-settings-object-subdivision) which also makes it less intense for your computer.

The Cycles material node system also has some versatile tools tools for achieving much of what I think you want to do. Some prefer old school Blender and I'm not judging.

I've attached the simplified file I tested - pictured above - in case someone has more solutions to offer...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I cant find `Mapping` below `Image mapping` in my texture tab...

Comment: You are using Blender Render right? Can't match your screen in Cycles...

Comment: Sorry, I m using texture tab...just after materials (the icon with the Checkerboard), I use two modifiers : subsurface and Displace. There is a sub tab for displacement map in texture tab (that's where i am).

Comment: Look again - Mapping should be under the Texture tab - it may be collapsed but just click on the triangle. If you want you can load your file here to check for you. Upload instruction here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: There is only `Custom Properties` tab under :( Thanks a lot for your help brother! Here is the file --> http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2730/

Comment: Sorry also, I'm using blender render, I didin't know what you meaned :)

Comment: Okay - the file is not what I expected - will have a look during lunch today. When you send textures you should pack them - File > External data > Pack all into blend file. That said hopefully your image files are not too big. Will try put together a simplified version...

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, if you want i can pack the texture, but is a simple seamless tile...